# hql: lead then create table, get wrong lead data

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hql

Bad case:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp12 AS
   WITH tmp_table AS
(
SELECT dt, time, LEAD(time,1,'99999') OVER(PARTITION BY urs) AS last_time, urs, tag FROM
    (
        SELECT dt, urs, time, tag, count(1) FROM table0 LIMIT 10000
    ) t1
GROUP BY dt, urs, time, tag
ORDER BY urs, time
)
```

Then

```
select * from tmp12
```

I get wrong data like:

[WRONG RESULT(dt, time, last_time, urs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyNyl.png)

There are some last_time < time.

When I remove CREATE TABLE, I get a good case:

```sql
SELECT dt, time, LEAD(time,1,'99999') OVER(PARTITION BY  urs) AS last_time, urs, tag FROM
    (
        SELECT dt, urs, time, tag, count(1) FROM table0 LIMIT 10000
    ) t1
GROUP BY dt, urs, time, tag
ORDER BY urs, time
```

with correct result like:

[GOOD RESULT(dt, time, last_time, urs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV2cp.png)

all the last_time > time.

Why? I just create table and then select from it, but the last_time becomes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp12 AS
   WITH tmp_table AS
(
SELECT dt, time, LEAD(time,1,'99999') OVER(PARTITION BY urs ORDER BY time) AS last_time, urs, tag FROM
    (
        SELECT dt, urs, time, tag, count(1) FROM table0 LIMIT 10000
    ) t1
GROUP BY dt, urs, time, tag
ORDER BY urs, time
)
```

I am guessing that the missing order by in the window function is the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, `PARTITION BY urs ORDER BY time` get correct result. But I am still consufed that why the good case I have mentioned in my question description can also get right result, but the bad case can't.

Comment: @qiu You can accept the answer then. When you are using WINDOW function you need to specify the order of the rows as to guarantee its behavior. In your good case, you just got a kind of lucky -  I guess because of the outer ORDER BY, which seems to be ignore when you have CREATE TABLE.